# Pass parameters to downstream projects

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I would like to concatenate some projects in Jenkins and make sure that they can all access the Git parameters (`${GIT_REVISION}`, `${GIT_BRANCH}` etc.) from the original project.

I tried using the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin), but I'm not sure what options I have to turn on where. It does *not* appear to work out of the box.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Predefined parameters" option with a value of `GIT_BRANCH=${GIT_BRANCH}` to pass the `GIT_BRANCH` variable to the downstream job. You can't use the "Current build parameters" options because `GIT_BRANCH` is a build variable, not a build parameter. So you have to explicitly map all variables that should be passed to the downstream job.

If you want to pass the Git commit to the downstream job in order to checkout the same commit, use the "Pass-through Git Commit that was built" option along with a Git SCM source in the downstream job. That option will automagically cause the downstream job to checkout the same Git commit as the upstream job.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using the Workflow feature (as in your question tag): use the *Workflow: Multibranch* plugin (currently released on the experimental update center—[details](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#multibranch-projects)), and write the whole pipeline as one Workflow job. You can have as many `node {}` blocks as you need for different slaves and workspaces, but in each one `checkout scm` will check out the same Git revision, matching your `Jenkinsfile` control script.